How to override/update kong-rockspec file to change version of a dependency?
I am using kong for my api management and the version am using is 0.11.0 (very old) and Postgres version is 10.x.
We have an requirement to update the postgres to community edition (15.x) and it needs to be supported immediately.
I know I need to update the kong, but as if now as an immediate fix I wanted resolve this without updating kong. I know the issue lies in kong-0.11.0-0.rockspec where we have a dependencies named 'pgmoon' version 1.8.0. So basically I need to get this version updated to 1.12.0 as part of this issue https://github.com/leafo/pgmoon/pull/101.
and I cannot change anything in Postgres with this regard.
So I want to understand how can I override/change the dependecy version in my application since kong is a 3rd party application and I cannot modify the source code.

Does kong not build if you make a local rockspec file where you specify the pgmoon version as 1.12.0? in the kong-0.11.0-0.rockspec you will find a table called dependencies and can change "pgmoon == 1.8.0" to "pgmoon == 1.12.0"

@Nifim ya thats what I want to achieve but how can I make changes in the source code? How would I generate the .rpm file out of it post that

This is a scrambled step by step of how I'd do this
Step 1: Obtain the Kong Code Source

Obtain the source code of the Kong version you are running. You can clone the Kong repository from GitHub:
git clone https://github.com/Kong/kong.git
Navigate to the directory housing the code source:
cd kong
Step 2: Find the rockspec File

Locate the rockspec file for the Kong version you are running. Look for kong-0.11.0-0.rockspec file.
Step 3: Modify the Dependencies

Once you have located the rockspec file, you can modify the dependencies section to override the version of pgmoon. Open the rockspec file in a text editor and locate the dependencies table. Change the version of pgmoon from 1.8.0 to 1.12.0:
dependencies = { -- ... leafo.pgmoon { version = "1.12.0" }, -- ... }
Step 4: Now Rebuild Kong

After modifying the rockspec file, you need to rebuild Kong. You can do this using LuaRocks:
luarocks make
This will rebuild the Kong package with the overridden dependency version.
Step 5: Install the Rebuilt Kong

Finally, you can install the rebuilt Kong package. If you are using a package manager like apt or yum, you will need to remove the existing Kong package before installing the new one. After that, you can install the new Kong package using the package manager.
Alternatively, if you are not using a package manager, you can install Kong manually by copying the rebuilt package to the appropriate directory. For example, if you are using a Linux system, you can copy the package to /usr/local:
sudo cp kong-*.tar.gz /usr/local/
Then, extract the package and install Kong:
sudo tar xzf /usr/local/kong-*.tar.gz -C /usr/local/ sudo ln -s /usr/local/kong/bin/kong /usr/local/bin/
